# function def show_table create a and return a formatted string representing the 2D table

Tags: python, string, format

With my code, I am having trouble with spacing and also finding a way to determine the length of each column that way I know when to have a newline.
Columns are separated with a single vertical bar '|'; and there must be exactly one space
before and after the vertical bar;
o Every row starts and ends with a vertical bar; and there must be exactly one space after the
leading bar and before the ending bar 
This is my code I have so far:

```
def show_table(table):
    string = '' 
    for i in table: 
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = i[j]
            string += "{}".format(line) + "|"

    return "|" + string +"\n"
```

There is one Restriction: you must use string formatting, either % or .format().
Below is an example of a list of lists
This is an Example:

```
>>> show_table([['A','BB'],['C','DD']])
'| A | BB |\n| C | DD |\n'
>>> print(show_table([['A','BB'],['C','DD']])) 
| A | BB |
| C | DD |
```

Comment: it looks like you never accept any answers for your questions. While this is completely optional, please consider using the feature in order to help future readers of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty close, but you haven't got the proper spaces around the vertical bars, and you aren't handling the end of each line in the table.

You don't need to worry about the width of the columns because your assignment description says to put exactly one space between the list items and the vertical bars.

Here's a repaired version of your code with minimal changes.

```
def show_table(table):
    string = '' 
    for i in table: 
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = i[j]
            string += '| {} '.format(i[j])
        string += '|\n'

    return string

print(show_table([['A','BB'],['C','DD']]))
```

**output**

```
| A | BB |
| C | DD |
```

It's more Pythonic to iterate directly over a list, rather than iterating indirectly using the list index.

```
def show_table(table):
    string = '' 
    for line in table: 
        for item in line:
            string += '| {} '.format(item)
        string += '|\n'

    return string
```

A more compact way is to use a list comprehension:

```
def show_table(table):
    return ''.join(['| {} |\n'.format(' | '.join(row)) for row in table])
```

Comment: I have another test case that Im not passing, it looks like this '| A   | B   |\n| CCC | DDD |\n', where A and B have at least three spaces in between the letter to its end of the vertical bar. how do I adjust that?

Comment: @brian012: That output is correct if "there must be exactly one space before and after the vertical bar; Every row starts and ends with a vertical bar; and there must be exactly one space after the leading bar and before the ending bar".